# Can someone explain what is happening with this unique_ptr code?

Tags: c++, c++11, scope, unique-ptr

This is a code that uses unique_ptr:

```
struct Foo{
  Foo(){std::cout << "Ctor called\n";}
  ~Foo(){std::cout << "Dtor called\n";}
  void bar(){std::cout << "bar called\n";}
}

int main(){
 unique_ptr<Foo> up(new Foo);
 {
  vector<unique_ptr<Foo>> v;
  v.push_back(move(up));
 }

 up->bar();
 return 0;
}
```

The output of the run is:

```
Ctor called
Dtor called
bar called
```

I was expecting the call to `bar()` fail because from what i have understood, `up` was supposed to get destroyed with `v` because of the `move`ing. Looks like i haven't understood correctly. Can someone walk me through what is happening? (g++ 4.7.0)

Comment: Undefined behavior is not defined to show failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see is *undefined behavior*, caused by the last call `up->bar()`. Its probably be the same if you try:

```
static_cast<Foo*>(0)->bar();
```

Note that *undefined behavior* really means *undefined*, so it could crash or do somewhat totally unexpected, like appearing to work ok. The compiler could also understand that the last line of code will never be reached *(under defined behavior)*, and decide to generate an empty executable that does nothing at all.

Answer (score 3):

> from what i have understood, `up` was supposed to get destroyed with `v` because of the `move`ing.

It was destroyed. Why else would `"Dtor called"` show up on the output? An object is destroyed when the destructor executes. No other magic happens.

> I was expecting the call to bar() fail

You can't expect anything when the behaviour is undefined, which is the case for dereferencing an empty `unique_ptr`.